# Anniversary Celebrations

Tags: discussion

Music: Practice & Theory is turning ten years old! (If you’re curious, you can see our very first question [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1/21766).) To celebrate, Stack Exchange is collecting some thoughts for a blog post to celebrate us and other communities that are turning ten this quarter.

For this blog post, Stack Exchange is looking for a few possible ideas:

- A brief history of Music.SE
- Thoughts on what makes Music.SE special
- Any interesting/fun/memorable stories or experiences from Music.SE
- What drew you to Music.SE in the first place, and/or why you keep coming back

In the answer space below, feel free to address any of the above questions—and anything similar you might want to add!—that you think could have a spot in the blog post. Once we’ve collected the material, we can collaborate to determine how best to share the information.

Lastly, we can opt to have a temporary “Ten-Year Anniversary” banner on our site; the banner will last for one month. Please vote on [this answer](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3696/21766) to help determine if we want this temporary banner.

Expect more information soon. But in the meantime, congratulations and thanks for being such a great community!

Doktor Mayhem, Dom, and Richard

Comment: I'm a relative newcomer, so I'm still hoping for some "interesting/fun/memorable stories or experiences" from the old days. Like, back when Music.SE was operated on punch cards.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

“Ten-Year Anniversary” Banner Voting

**Upvote this answer** if you **want** the temporary banner.

**Downvote this answer** if you **do not want** the temporary banner.

Comment: The banner is snazzy. If banners could be upvoted, I'd do it twice.